# warning appears more than once

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, warnings, capslock

Just a quick question, if i leave the caps lock on it will appear the Warning message 3 times? i only want it to appear once

```
            jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                  for( int i=0; i < users.size(); i++ ){
                     temp = (logins)users.elementAt(i);
                     if( Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
                        getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK))
                     {
                        check = "true";
                        {
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                              null, "Please turn off the capslock", "Error",
                              JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            });
            pack();
            this.setSize(643, 434);
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"Warning message 3 times"*  What is the value of `users.size()`?  I'd bet it has 3 elements.

Answer (score 2):

You have done

```
check = true;
```

but it's never checked, add it into `if`

```
if( Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK)
   && ! check )
{
   check = "true";
   ...
```

**or, better, put it outside the loop since the condition of the `if` doesn't use the data iterated...**